# Develop in series Mac-Laurin the function $f(x)={\frac{x^2}{1-x}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, euler-maclaurin

I just want to know if what I did was good because I did not fully understood this theorem.
I have this function: $$f(x)={\frac{x^2}{1-x}}$$ And I have to develop her in series Mac Laurin. Firstly I've used the geometric series for ${\frac{1}{x^n}}$ to do this $f(x)=x^2\sum_{n\ge0}{\frac{(-1)^n}{x^n}}=\sum_{n\ge0}{\frac{(-1)^nx^2}{x^n}}=\sum_{n\ge0}{\frac{(-1)^n}{x^{n-2}}}=\sum_{n\ge0}{\frac{1}{(-x)^{n-2}}}$ It is correct what I did? If yes, is this the final form of the series Mac-Laurin or shoul I do something more to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MacLaurin series representation for $\frac1{1-x}$ is given by

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$

for $|x|<1$.  The is simply a geometric series.

---

Hence, the series representation for $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{1-x}$ is

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\frac{x^2}{1-x}\\\\
&=x^2\frac{1}{1-x}\\\\
&=x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+2}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=2}^\infty x^{n}
\end{align}$$

for $|x|<1$.

---

For $|x|>1$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=\frac{x^2}{1-x}\\\\
&=-\frac{x}{1-1/x}\\\\
&=-x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left( \frac{1}{x}\right)^n\\\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left( \frac{1}{x}\right)^{n-1}\\\\
&=-\sum_{n=-1}^\infty x^{-n}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I like this answer, but since the poster is obviously not super well-versed in summation manipulation, perhaps showing the multiplication by $x^2$ and then the index shift to $n=2$ as intermediate steps? I'll admit it took me a second to see what you had done.

Comment: @TheCount Good point. I'll edit.

Comment: I was realy confused. I forgot the sum of a geometric series is ${\frac{1}{1-x}}$, where x is ratio.. I got the ratio $r=\frac{1}{n}$. Thx again

Comment: @NeacsuMihai You're welcome. My pleasure.  -Mark